# display reference columns in multi-child SQL

Tags: sql, join, group-by, ssms, distinct

```
-------  id   -------  id   -------  id   -------  id   -------
| t-1 | <---> | t-a | <---> | t-b | <---> | s-a | <---> | s-b |
-------       -------       -------       -------       ------- 

SELECT distinct 
   t-a.col, t-b.col
FROM 
   INNER JOIN t-1 ON t-1.id = t-a.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN t-b on t-a.id = t-b.id
GROUP BY
   T-1.id
```

So what I want is to display a column from s-b (along with all the other columns being displayed) which is referenced by s-a which is referenced by t-b. I can display anything I want from t-a and t-b but I get errors trying to link up the other sub tables.

```
SELECT  distinct
        inspections.inspection_id as InspectionId,
        convert(char(3),inspections.Inspection_Type) + ' ' + Inspection_Desc as Inspection,
        inspections.current_status as Current_Status,
        case when left(inspections.current_status,1) = 'X' then 'SCHEDULED' else inspection_status.status_description end as Current_Status_Name,
        convert(varchar(10),max(distinct inspection_history.scheduled_date),101) as 'Last_Scheduled',
        convert(varchar(10),max(distinct inspection_history.inspect_date),101) as 'Last_Inspected',
        inspections.inspection_type,
        case when (inspections.current_status <> 'A' and left(inspections.current_status,1) <> 'X' and left(inspections.current_status,1) <> 'S') then dbo.fn_DependencyCheckMessage(@PermitNum,inspections.inspection_type) else '' end as Dependency_Message,
        case when (inspections.current_status <> 'A' and left(inspections.current_status,1) <> 'X' and left(inspections.current_status,1) <> 'S') and (dbo.fn_DependencyCheck(@PermitNum,inspections.inspection_type)=1 and dbo.fn_CheckTempDeposits(@PermitNum,inspections.inspection_type)=1 and dbo.fn_CertOccCheck(@PermitNum,inspections.inspection_type)=1) then 1 else 0 end as AllowSchedule, 
        inspection_comments.comment_description as comment

    FROM inspections

        inner join permit_arch on permit_arch.permit_id = Inspections.permit_id
        inner join inspection_types on inspection_types.inspection_type = Inspections.inspection_type
        LEFT OUTER JOIN inspection_history ON inspections.inspection_id = inspection_history.inspection_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN inspection_status ON inspections.current_status = inspection_status.status_code

        LEFT JOIN inspection_history_comment ON inspection_history.insp_hist_id = inspection_history_comment.inspection_history_id
        LEFT JOIN inspection_comments ON inspection_history_comment.comment_code = inspection_comments.comment_code

    WHERE

        permit_arch.permit_number = @PermitNum
        AND
        (inspection_types.internal_only is null or inspection_types.internal_only = 0)
        AND
        (inspection_history.status <> 'D' or inspection_history.status is null)

    GROUP BY permit_arch.permit_number,permit_arch.permit_status, inspections.Inspection_Type, inspection_types.inspection_desc, inspections.current_status,inspection_status.status_description, 
                 inspections.inspection_id

    HAVING Permit_arch.permit_number = @Permitnum and (inspections.current_status <> 'D' or inspections.current_status is null) and inspections.inspection_type <> 34

    ORDER BY inspections.inspection_type ASC
```

My joins are the last two. SSMS errors with:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure procWebGetPermitInspectionsForSchedulingA, Line 20 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   Column 'inspection_comments.comment_description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure procWebGetPermitInspectionsForSchedulingA, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 7]
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

I want to get the column `inspection_comments.description`

Comment: can you please post the error

Comment: see yellow box above

Comment: Add that column in the group by and remove order by and recheck your result

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks @maSTAShuFu

Comment: appreciate if you +1

Comment: I would if I had that option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `group by` in your query. It is used when there is an aggregated function like `sum, max` etc. in `select` statement. You also missed mentioning `t-a` before `inner join` in your query. I have included that in my query.

Also, `Left outer join` is nothing but `Left join` itself. Therefore, I changed that also in the query

Try this:-

```
SELECT distinct 
   t-a.col, t-b.col, s-b.col
FROM t-a
   INNER JOIN t-1 ON t-1.id = t-a.id
   LEFT JOIN t-b on t-a.id = t-b.id
   LEFT JOIN s-a on t-b.id=s-a.id
   LEFT JOIN s-b on s-a.id=s-b.id;
```

Comment: see my edits with actual code. The last two joins are the ones that would take me to the column I need.